# Third element goes on next line on IE

Tags: css, alignment

So I have a header bar that's something like [IMG______TITLE______IMG]

I have something like this, where all 3 elements are in 1 div:

```
#left_image {
    display:block;
    width:80px;
    height:100%;
    float:left;
}

#middle_div {
    width:1030px;
    height:100%;
    text-align:center;
    display:inline-block;
}

#left_image {
    display:block;
    width:80px;
    height:100%;
    float:right;
}
```

But for some reason, only on IE, the last picture is on the next line, like:

[IMG_______title__________]

[______________________IMG]

You can see the last image is still going to the far right, but for some reason outside of the containing div...Any idea how to properly horizontally align these?

Comment: You should add the minimal code necessary to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Do these divs need to be a specific width? Can you use percentages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this without floats, and some simple positioning:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="left">Left things</div>
    <div class="middle">Middle things</div>
    <div class="right">Right things</div>
</div>

.wrapper {width:100%;background-color:#eee;position:relative;}
.left,.middle,.right {display:inline-block;padding:10px;}
.middle {text-align:center;}
.right {position:absolute;right:0;}
```

Here's a link to a demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/76t8ca7h/

---

Updated fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/76t8ca7h/3/

and new css:

```
.wrapper {width:100%;min-width:100%;background-color:#eee;padding:0;margin:0;overflow:hidden;}
.left,.middle,.right {display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;float:left;}
.middle {text-align:center;width:60%;}
.left,.right {width:20%;background-color:#ccc;}
.right {float:right;}
```

Comment: This will fork fine if I set the widths to add up to the width of the container, but what if I wanted the middle thing to be centered. You can see in the demo that is is shifted to the left

Comment: Ah, I overlooked that. Give me a bit and I will find a better solution for you.

Comment: I updated my answer to get closer to what you'd like.